# Try to have the Month and the day two digit in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have a StoredProcedure for Project table I want to select "ProjectStartDate" with format MMDDYYYY -> 07092021 and the data is going to print on an Excel spread sheet.
The code that I wrote is:

```html
 select
 replace(convert(varchar, pp.ProjectStartDate,110),'-','')
 from Project pp
```

But on the spread sheet the Month is 1 digit 7092021.
Please advice, Thank you

Comment: This is NOT a SQL issue -- [Keeping leading zeros and large numbers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7)

Comment: In reality, you'll end up finding that you do NOT want to SELECT the date with a particular format. Rather, you'll find that you want to format the date at the presentation layer (Excel, WinForm, web page, report, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use

```
date_format(ProjectStartDate,'%m%d%Y')
```